# How to increase the buffer size of USB in android

Tags: android, usb

I am writing an application i.e. communication between android device and micro controller by virtual comm port using usb cable.But here i want to receive data of 3000 bytes but in usb it was limit up to 64 bytes buffer for usb.My question is How to increase the size of usb port from 64 bytes to 3000 bytes.?
RASAP  please

```
Thread Receive  = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(3050);
        byte[] sample = new byte[3050];
        int Frame_Size;
        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int i,j;
        byte [] datarx=new byte[1]; 
        char q;
        while (true) 
        {
        request.initialize(UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection, UsbDriver.Data_In_End_Point);
       // request.queue(buffer, 3050);      ----------->> Here the buffer size was notexceeded from 64 how to increase to 3050
      //  if (UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection.requestWait() == request) 
            if(UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection.bulkTransfer(UsbDriver.Data_In_End_Point,sample, 3050, 500)>=0)
            {
    //  sample=buffer.array(); 
                for(i=0;i<3050;i++)
                {
                        if(sample[i]=='&')
                        {
                            Communication_Ok=true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(sample[i]==0x03)
                        {
                            if(sample[0]==0x02)
                            Frame_Ok=true;  
                            break;
                        }
                }
                if(Frame_Ok==true)
                {
                    Frame_Ok=false;

                    Frame_Size=(int)(((sample[2]&0x00FF)<<8) + (sample[3]&0x00FF));
          //        Frame_Size=Frame_Size/2;
                    for(i=4,j=0;i<Frame_Size;i=i+2,j++)
                    {
                    //  Wave_Form_Data[j]=(int)(sample[i] + sample[i+1]);   
                    //  Wave_Form_Data_1[j] = (float)((((int)(((sample[i]&0x00FF)<<8) + (sample[i+1]&0x00FF)))*(float)3.3)/4096);
                        Wave_Form_Data_1[j]= (int)(((sample[i]&0x00FF)<<8) + (sample[i+1]&0x00FF));
                    }
            //      Respsonse_Time=(float)((int)(((sample[Frame_Size]&0x00FF)<<8) + (sample[Frame_Size+1]&0x00FF)));
            //      Drive_Voltage=(float)((int)(((sample[Frame_Size+2]&0x00FF)<<8) + (sample[Frame_Size+3]&0x00FF)));
                    for(j=0;j<Frame_Size/2;j++)
                        Wave_Form_Data[j] =(float) ((Wave_Form_Data_1[j]*3.3)/4095);    
            //      Respsonse_Time=Drive_Voltage=(++Temp);
                    if((sample[1]-0x30)==1)
                    Coil_No=1;
                    else
                    Coil_No=2;  
                    Total_Frame_Decoded=true;

                }
                sample = null;
            }   
        }
     }
    });
```

Comment: what buffer are you talking about?

Comment: Usb buffer?  Any link in sdk documentation?

Comment: Actually it was a byte buffer for USB i am receiving data from a controller in a thread and here's the allocation of usb buffer size and but it was taking only upto 64bitsonly here's bytebuffer allocation :::------->>>>                                                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(3050);
  byte[] sample = new byte[3050];

Comment: What are you talking about? What api are you using?

Comment: API 18 i paste my code to receive data from controller